# How to copy the values of an object to another object without doing it manually

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have this Problem with the put request in asp Net core.

```
var data = await _service.GetReceiptOrderByIdAsync(request.Id, false, cancellationToken);
        if (data == null)
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(ReceiptOrder), request.Id);
        
        data = _mapper.Map<ReceiptOrder>(request.ReceiptOrderForUpdateDto);
        
        await _service.SaveChangeAsync(cancellationToken);
```

the put request is not successful because the ef core is not detecting changes, but if I do it manually it get successful.
Example:

```
var data = await _service.GetReceiptOrderByIdAsync(request.Id, false, cancellationToken);
        if (data == null)
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(ReceiptOrder), request.Id);
        
        data.IsPaid = true;
                await _service.SaveChangeAsync(cancellationToken);
```

the problem is when I do this code:

```
        data = _mapper.Map<ReceiptOrder>(request.ReceiptOrderForUpdateDto);
```

the data object gets the reference of the other object so ef core is not detecting the changes.

any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not documented the best, but Automapper has `Map` call for copying data from one instance to another:

```
var data = await _service.GetReceiptOrderByIdAsync(request.Id, false, cancellationToken);
if (data == null)
    throw new NotFoundException(nameof(ReceiptOrder), request.Id);
    
_mapper.Map(request.ReceiptOrderForUpdateDto, data);
    
await _service.SaveChangeAsync(cancellationToken);
```

This will copy values from your DTO into the existing data object. The problem with your original code is that `data = _mapper.Map(...)` will replace the reference to the entity so nothing is saved since you aren't updating the tracked entity, but replacing the reference with a new instance of the class built by Automapper.